# Completely remove Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

After removing Kubernetes 1.15 (master and worker node):

```
kubeadm reset
apt-get purge kubeadm kubectl kubelet kubernetes-cni kube*
```

and removing all config files and installing again 1.17 getting this error while joining cluster:

```
[kubelet-start] Downloading configuration for the kubelet from the "kubelet-config-1.15" ConfigMap in the kube-system namespace
error execution phase kubelet-start: configmaps "kubelet-config-1.15" is forbidden: User "system:bootstrap:fmhnus" cannot get resource "configmaps" in API group "" in the namespace "kube-system"
```

What did I miss and where?

Comment: Are you sure you did all steps mentioned by kooskoos? Also with `sudo rm -rf ~/.kube` ? How did you install this K8s 1.17, using official docs?: https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/install-kubeadm/#installing-kubeadm-kubelet-and-kubectl 
What did you do on master node before? Keep in mind that between 1.15 and 1.17 many apiVersions changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Follow these steps to completely remove Kubernetes

```
kubeadm reset
sudo apt-get purge kubeadm kubectl kubelet kubernetes-cni kube*   
sudo apt-get autoremove  
sudo rm -rf ~/.kube
```

`kubeadm reset` un-configures the cluster made by kubernetes.

Comment: More to read on [kubeadm reset](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/kubeadm-reset/)